# Notepad++ page scroll on changing tab

Tags: notepad++

I just installed the latest version of Notepad++ (v.6.8) and I noticed something surprising. I have been using Notepad++ for a while and I am used to move from a tab to another for various reasons.

Here is my problem: when switching from a tab to another, and then switching back to my initial tab (tab1 -> tab2 -> tab1), I notice that notepad++ does not keep in memory the location of the pointer on tab1, and scrolls me back up in tab1.

This is quite annoying as it forces me to scroll down back where I am working every time I switch tabs.

Has anyone noticed such behavior ? Can it be deactivated somewhere ?

Comment: I have this issue too, but only for a single file.  I don't know what's going on, or how to fix it.

Comment: Any solution? Its 2018 now and this problem still persists.

Answer (score 16):

If you have XML Tools plugin try to disable "Set XML type automatically" (`Plugins` -> `XML Tools` -> `Set XML type automatically`).

Taken from [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/33/return-to-same-line-when-switching-tabs/).

Worked for me.
BTW, it is fixed in XML Tools 2.4.7

Comment: I'm not using XML Tools. Tried everything, using latest version. Still having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just noticed the same behavior.
In "Preferences -> Multi-Instance", I choose "Always", and it seem to be fixed.

I can not guarantee the efficiency of this solution, but you can try it out!

Comment: Alexandre, it did not seem to fix the issue in my case. I notice that this behavior seems dependent on the tab content as a ".tex" file will be scrolled up but not a ".bib" file for instance... puzzling !

Comment: That's very strange... I just made several tests, with different extensions, and switching "Multi-Instance option", but the behavior you described seem fixed in my case.

Comment: This behavior was driving me nuts and I couldn't find any suggestions for it. This preference change worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have added some empty lines at the end of the file, the problem solved.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried.  It did not help.